# How can I solve installation error of texthero?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, data-preprocessing

When I tried to `!pip install texthero` on Google Colab, below error happen therefore I cannot import texthero.

- code of pip install

```
!pip install texthero
```

- result message with error after `pip install`

```
Collecting texthero
  Downloading texthero-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Collecting gensim<4.0,>=3.6.0 (from texthero)
  Downloading gensim-3.8.3.tar.gz (23.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.4/23.4 MB 22.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Building wheels for collected packages: gensim
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for gensim (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gensim
  Running setup.py clean for gensim
Failed to build gensim
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gensim, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

- error message after `import texthero as hero`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'texthero'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because of incompatibility issues between different versions of libraries.you can specify a particular version

```
!pip install gensim==3.6.0
!pip install texthero==1.1.0
```

this version works I've tried it
output:

```
Collecting gensim==3.6.0
  Downloading gensim-3.6.0.tar.gz (23.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.1/23.1 MB 57.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim==3.6.0) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.18.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim==3.6.0) (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim==3.6.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: smart_open>=1.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim==3.6.0) (6.3.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: gensim
  Building wheel for gensim (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for gensim: filename=gensim-3.6.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=23916489 sha256=7bfecf602e2e3f97fe2d27228073b7c0feacf8c40dbab0e4657759157d5c66f8
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/00/e8/47/96f55c3144a5ea3537f549f7a97607011f5004b9f13fa8dcc5
Successfully built gensim
Installing collected packages: gensim
  Attempting uninstall: gensim
    Found existing installation: gensim 4.3.1
    Uninstalling gensim-4.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled gensim-4.3.1
Successfully installed gensim-3.6.0
Collecting texthero==1.1.0
  Using cached texthero-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.22 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (1.2.2)
Collecting spacy<3.0.0 (from texthero==1.1.0)
  Using cached spacy-2.3.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (4.65.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: plotly>=4.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (5.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wordcloud>=1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (1.8.2.2)
Collecting unidecode>=1.1.1 (from texthero==1.1.0)
  Using cached Unidecode-1.3.6-py3-none-any.whl (235 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: gensim<4.0,>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from texthero==1.1.0) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.18.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim<4.0,>=3.6.0->texthero==1.1.0) (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim<4.0,>=3.6.0->texthero==1.1.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: smart-open>=1.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim<4.0,>=3.6.0->texthero==1.1.0) (6.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.1.0->texthero==1.1.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.1.0->texthero==1.1.0) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.1.0->texthero==1.1.0) (4.40.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.1.0->texthero==1.1.0) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.1.0->texthero==1.1.0) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.1.0->texthero==1.1.0) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.1.0->texthero==1.1.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.1.0->texthero==1.1.0) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nltk>=3.3->texthero==1.1.0) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nltk>=3.3->texthero==1.1.0) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: regex>=2021.8.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nltk>=3.3->texthero==1.1.0) (2022.10.31)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas>=1.0.2->texthero==1.1.0) (2022.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity>=6.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from plotly>=4.2.0->texthero==1.1.0) (8.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.22->texthero==1.1.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (3.0.8)
Collecting thinc<7.5.0,>=7.4.1 (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0)
  Using cached thinc-7.4.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.8.0,>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (0.7.9)
Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.4.0 (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0)
  Using cached wasabi-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=1.0.2 (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0)
  Using cached srsly-1.0.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (209 kB)
Collecting catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7 (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0)
  Using cached catalogue-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (67.7.2)
Collecting plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6 (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0)
  Using cached plac-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (1.26.16)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (2023.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<3.0.0->texthero==1.1.0) (3.4)
Installing collected packages: wasabi, plac, unidecode, srsly, catalogue, thinc, spacy, texthero
  Attempting uninstall: wasabi
    Found existing installation: wasabi 1.1.2
    Uninstalling wasabi-1.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled wasabi-1.1.2
  Attempting uninstall: srsly
    Found existing installation: srsly 2.4.6
    Uninstalling srsly-2.4.6:
      Successfully uninstalled srsly-2.4.6
  Attempting uninstall: catalogue
    Found existing installation: catalogue 2.0.8
    Uninstalling catalogue-2.0.8:
      Successfully uninstalled catalogue-2.0.8
  Attempting uninstall: thinc
    Found existing installation: thinc 8.1.10
    Uninstalling thinc-8.1.10:
      Successfully uninstalled thinc-8.1.10
  Attempting uninstall: spacy
    Found existing installation: spacy 3.5.3
    Uninstalling spacy-3.5.3:
      Successfully uninstalled spacy-3.5.3
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
confection 0.0.4 requires srsly<3.0.0,>=2.4.0, but you have srsly 1.0.6 which is incompatible.
en-core-web-sm 3.5.0 requires spacy<3.6.0,>=3.5.0, but you have spacy 2.3.9 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed catalogue-1.0.2 plac-1.1.3 spacy-2.3.9 srsly-1.0.6 texthero-1.1.0 thinc-7.4.6 unidecode-1.3.6 wasabi-0.10.1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I have tried your suggestion, however, another error happened, when I ran code `import texthero as hero`:


`/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py in <module>
      9 from __future__ import with_statement
     10 
---> 11 from collections import Mapping, defaultdict
     12 import sys
     13 import logging

ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)`


Then I tried add `from _collections_abc import Mapping` on __init__.py, but it did not work as well...